# Run angular end-to-end tests in watch mode

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-e2e

Currently, I run ng e2e every time I make a change in my spec files and every time this command rebuilds the entire project ! is there a way to run the tests without rebuilding the entire project, just like ng test does it.

Answer (score 5):

Just don't run `ng e2e` directly. It's very slow because it rebuild the whole project every time.

You can try `npx protractor e2e/protractor.conf.js` to run `protractor` directly.

Comment: the fastest workflow I've got was this `npx protractor ...` + vscode's rerun task keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

Remove

```
devServerTarget
```

from angular.json e2e section.

This way angular won't run `ng serve` when running the end to end. You will have to have them running in a separate terminal.

Protractor won't re-run on file change.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can do it yourself with a bit of set up by leveraging the powers of Gulp. Just came across this while watching some slides:

http://ramonvictor.github.io/protractor/slides/#/53